# БД SQLite чтение даты и времени и интервал между первым запуском и текущей датой

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite3

В общем суть проблемы такова. Есть база данных sqlite с таблицей users в которой есть следующие столбцы

```
id  user_id user_login user_name second_name         clock
1   12345    @telegram   Вася      Пупкин        2018-06-13 13:48:27.862641
2   54321    @margelet   Иван      Иванов        2018-06-10 20:13:45.526941
```

Необходимо при входе пользователя 12345 прочесть его дату первого входа "2018-06-13 13:48:27.862641" и просчитать интервал с его текущей датой, и при нажатии определенной кнопки вывести все это ему в сообщении наподобии "вы находитесь в боте уже столько то дней"
И таким образом что бы остальные пользователи получали свое время пребывание

Сразу прошу подробный ответ с примерами скрипта т.к. я совсем еще новичек

Comment: против вождя не попрешь, раз Сталин просит, нужно отвечать :) А на самом деле, вы сами пытались что-то сделать? Лучше если  вы приведете пример того, что вы пытались сделать и что у вас не получилось

Comment: естественно пытался пробовал через delta просчитать разницу но не могу вытащить нужную дату из бд

Comment: @Stalin Если пробовали, то дополните вопрос тем, что получилось.

Comment: Да опробовал вот аналогичный вопрос только немножко расширенный в котором мне помогли https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/841944/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В днях:

```
select julianday('now') - julianday(min(clock)) as days
from tab where user_id=12345;
```

В часах:

```
select 24 * (julianday('now') - julianday(min(clock))) as hours 
from tab where user_id=12345;
```

[Тест на SQL Fiddle ...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/b4875/5)

Comment: Как это все впихнуть в скрипт наподобие этого @bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"]) 
def key(message):
    if message.text == 'Кол-во дней':
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id, Ваше время проведенное в боте "..." д. \n\n'
Что бы каждому пользователю выдавало своего количество дней?

Comment: Задайте отдельный (новый) вопрос. Вопрос в комментарии не имеет ничего общего с `"чтением даты и времени из БД SQLite"`

Comment: Я создал прошу если вы еще не заметили помогите если знаете как правильно реализовать?
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/841944/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80

Comment: @Stalin, я с `telegram-bot` никогда не работал, поэтому с этим вопросом пользы от меня мало...