# Как отправить пользователю при нажатии кнопки сообщение о его количестве дней проведенных в боте

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram-bot

Суть такова имеется скрипт телеграм бота

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
keyboard.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(name) for name in ['Старт']])
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Добро пожаловать\n\n', reply_markup=keyboard, parse_mode="Html", disable_web_page_preview=True)
AddUser (message.chat.id, message.chat.username, message.chat.first_name, message.chat.last_name, now)
```

Есть БД SQLite

```
def AddUser(user_id, user_login, user_name, second_name, clock):

# Подключаемся к SQLite
conn = sqlite3.connect('user.db')
c = conn.cursor()

# Обработка SQL исключений
try:
    # Выполняем SQL запрос
    c.execute("INSERT INTO users (user_id, user_login, user_name, second_name, clock) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", (user_id, user_login, user_name, second_name, clock))
except sqlite3.DatabaseError as error:
    # В случаи ошибки
    print("Error:", error)

# Завершаем транзикцию
conn.commit()
# Закрываем соединение
conn.close()
```

И собственно сама кнопка при нажатии которой пользователь должен видеть сколько дней с момента первого запуска уже прошло

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def key(message):

    if message.text == 'Кол-во дней':
 bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ваше время проведенное в боте "..." д. \n\n')
```

Как все это дело объеденить с этим кодом, да так что бы каждый пользователь получал именно свое время?

```
select julianday('now') - julianday(min(clock)) as days
from tab where user_id=12345;
```

Comment: now как определяете? Можно использовать в INSERT message.date, дата  хранится в unix timestamp

Comment: now = datetime.datetime.now() Можно пример я совсем новичек

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запись в БД:

```
# обратите внимание на последний параметр
# message.date - в формате unix timestamp
AddUser (message.chat.id, message.chat.username, message.chat.first_name, message.chat.last_name, message.date)
```

Получение даты из БД и вычисление дельты в днях от текущей даты

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def key(message):

    if message.text == 'Кол-во дней':
        get_date_with_bd = get_time_user(12345)
        bot.send_message(
            message.chat.id, 
            'Ваше время проведенное в боте {0} д. \n\n'.format(
                (datetime.datetime.now() - get_date_with_bd).days
            )
        )

def get_time_user(user_id):    
    conn = sqlite3.connect('user.db')
    c = conn.cursor()      
    get_timestamp = c.execute("select clock from users where user_id = (?)", (user_id,))
    get_timestamp = count.fetchall()
    db.close() 
    return get_timestamp[0][0]
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за то что отозвались но не совсем понял что нужно подставить сюда get_date_with_bd = "получить_дату_из_шага_1"
В следствии чего выходит ошибка TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'
формат времени хранится в unix timestamp - 1529081120

Comment: Необходимо достать из БД дату и сравить с текущей, я добавил в пример функции как это можно сделать для вашего случая.

Comment: В общем либо я дурак либо лыжи не едут как бы я не старался что-то изменить вылазиет вот такая ошибка `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'int'`
И еще вопрос касаемо вот этой строчки `get_date_with_bd = get_time_user(12345)` это получается будет отоброжаться время пользователя с ID 12345 у всех что ли?

Comment: Эта функция на вход получает ID пользователя, возвращает время добавления. По ошибке - функция `get_time_user` возвращает `None`

Comment: Можно с вами как то связаться через какой-нибудь мессенджер дабы тут не засорять коменты?

Comment: пишите на почту dimanah10@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Немножко подправил код т.к. в предложенном варианте не хотел запускаться

```
import datetime
import time
import sqlite3


dt = datetime.datetime.now()
timestamp = time.mktime(dt.timetuple())

def get_time_user(user_id):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('user.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    count = c.execute("select clock from users where user_id = (?)", (user_id,))
    get_timestamp = count.fetchall()
    c.close()
    return get_timestamp[0][0]

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def key(message):

    if message.text == 'Кол-во дней':
        get_date_with_bd = get_time_user(12345)  # example: select clock from users where user_id=12345;
        t = dt.fromtimestamp(timestamp - get_date_with_bd)
        days = t.strftime('%d')
        bot.send_message(
            message.chat.id,
            'Ваше время проведенное в боте {0}' .format(
                (days)
            )
        )
```

Но остается одна ошибка которую все никак не могу исправить, если дата совпадает с текущей либо отличается всего в одни сутки выпадает следующая ошибка

```
t = dt.fromtimestamp(timestamp - get_date_with_bd)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Если прошло больше суток, скажем 2-3 дня то код работает на отлично и бот выдает кол-во дней!